# Scrapy How to Get Values from data-href

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a bunch of links, or things which can be appended to the root domain to make a link from https://www.media.mit.edu/groups

The html itself looks like this:

```
<div class="container-item listing-layout-item selectorgadget_selected" data-href="/groups/viral-communications/overview/" '="">   
<div class="container-item listing-layout-item  selectorgadget_suggested" data-href="/groups/social-machines/overview/" '="">
<div class="container-item listing-layout-item  selectorgadget_suggested" data-href="/groups/space-enabled/overview/" '="">
```

The link data is stored within the `data-href` part, and I have been trying to use CSS selectors to get this data.

When I use the Scrapy shell, I have been trying to use 
`response.css('.data-href::text').extract()` but it returns an empty list.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
response.xpath('//div/@data-href').extract()
```

to get required values